# Discrete Math - Determine truth value of each proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If 3 + 5 < 2, then 1 + 3 $\neq $ 4

Can someone kindly check my work?

Let p: 3 + 5 < 2 and q: 1 + 3 $\neq $ 4

(3 + 5) < 2 $\rightarrow$ (1 + 3) $\neq$ 4 
8 < 2 $\rightarrow $ 4 $\neq $ 4 
F $\rightarrow$ F 
F

Is it good practice to put this into a word statement or is it not necessary unless specifically instructed to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F \to F = T$. The "chart truth value" is:

$F \to T = T, F \to F = T, T \to F = F, T \to T = T$

Comment: ah thats right; two False evaluations = True correct? Making sure I'm reading this right, still trying to learn all this *sigh*

Comment: thanks again for the help on this problem. I wrote the truth table out and realized I put that F in there on that last F $\rightarrow $ F row and column.

Comment: Make sure you go over each line that the table says and can apply it to other situations...

Comment: Awesome thank u.. @Back2Basic